Is it possible to apply different protovalidate validation rules to the same protobuf message
I've been looking at using protovalidate to power a complicated API validation use case that I have.
Here is the scenario I have (simplified). I have a single proto message, let's call it FooRequest:
message FooRequest {
    string foo = 1;
}

FooRequest is the request type for an API that I'm building. This API can be called by lots of different clients, and depending on some properties of the client itself, I want to be able to enforce different validation rules on the foo message, e.g.
message FooRequest {
    string foo = 1 [(buf.validate.field).string = {
    // assert that the value of "foo" is "bar" if it is being called from the Bar service
    in: [
      "bar"
    ]
  }];
}

or
message FooRequest {
    string foo = 1 [(buf.validate.field).string = {
    // assert that the value of "foo" is "baz" if it is being called from the Baz service
    in: [
      "baz"
    ]
  }];
}

Some ways I could imagine solving this:

You could have a bunch of different XYZClientFooValidation messages that contain the same fields as FooRequest. When the server receives a FooRequest it could check the FooRequest against the corresponding client's Foo validation message. Some problems I can see with this: I don't know how to enforce at compile time that XYZClientFooValidation messages contain the same fields as FooRequest. I also don't know how to "check" the FooRequest against the corresponding Foo validation message. I guess you could marshal the FooRequest into json, then unmarshal the json into a XYZClientFooValidation type?
If there was some way to pass a configuration to the validator.Validate() method it might be possible to configure different validation rules. This seems like it would overly complicate the validation process, but it would theoretically work?
You could have a giant oneof in FooRequest that defines all the different validation options for foo. This complicates the API for clients since they need to make sure to pick the correct option when they call the API.
Something else?

Admittedly, I think this use case is not super well suited to protobuf/protovalidate, what with protobuf's lack of inheritance and subpar support for polymorphism. But I thought I would double check here to see what the experts think of this use case and see if there are ways to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Is there a technical challenge you're facing that requires you to re-use Request/Response messages in your service? Typically, we'd suggest not sharing top-level messages between multiple RPCs like this. By creating per-RPC Request/Response messages, it'd be easier for you to customize the validation rules, per-RPC.

The Request/Response message is being reused because it is the same API with the same fields in the request/response bodies. The API is powering a platform that can be used by many different clients and each client has different rules governing what values can be specified in the request's fields. It is perhaps more of an authorization problem than a schema validation problem, but I really like protovalidate's validation error messages and using an authorization tool like Cedar is overkill for our use case.

In my experience, being identical field is a temporally bounded reality. :) They all align today, but there are plenty of future possibilities where they may not. Arguably, having different validation semantics implies they are functionally separate already. I might create a wrapper for these pathways and consider using a oneof to select which client you're working with. My recommendation is to be more explicit with the contract types.
